# How to get autocomplete with customized dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I have to implement the customized dropdown for autocomplete but I am unable to get it, here on ng-change I am getting the response. But the problem is how to get the autocomplete by typing first three letters and have to move through the dropdown by using keyboard keys.

JavaScript:

```
  $scope.fnAutocompleteQuestion = function (question) {
       $scope.data = [
        { "val": 1, "txt": "one" },
        { "val": 2, "txt": "two" }, 
        { "val": 3, "txt": "three" },
        { "val": 4, "txt": "four" },
        { "val": 5, "txt": "five" }];
       console.log($scope.data);
   };
```

Html:

```
      <div class="input-group dropdown" ng-class="{'open': mydropdownQues}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.question" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" ng-change="fnAutocompleteQuestion(input.question);mydropdownQues=!mydropdownQues">
   <div class="dropdown-menu width-menu">
            <ul class="ul-scroll">
                <li ng-repeat="value in data " ng-click="input.question=value.txt">
                    {{value.txt}}
                    <hr ng-show="!$last">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: @ Nikhil Vartak No I need customized one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `filter: input.question` in your `ng-repeat` where `input.question` is `ng-model` for search text. Something like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="value in data | filter: input.question" ng-click="input.question=value.txt">
     {{value.txt}}
     <hr ng-show="!$last">
 </li>
```

[**working example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1yCVhrNDP25A7Lu5T69?p=preview)

Comment: Tq,but when Iam typing 2 letters,getting empty list.

Comment: @bpinky it depends on what you type.. if you type "fo", it displays four only. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: no when Iam using bootstrap it's not working otherwise it works fine.

Comment: check it with bootstrap once Iam not getting any response for two letters

Comment: @bpinky found it. `mydropdownQues=!mydropdownQues` was the culprit. for second char, this goes `false` and list gets hidden

Comment: @bpinky you should ask that as seperate question.. if I might not, someone else can help you.. but try it on your own first and then ask